# Axis2 WebService JMS Transport Soap Compression

Tags: java, apache-axis

**Problem:**
I want to implement a Web Service using Axis2 with JMS Transport-In, which can process incoming soap messages with compressed content.

**Questions:**

- Is this possible without additional configuration?
- Would it be enough for the client to just compress the message content?

**Background:**
Googling, I have found nothing regarding this topic (only client-side HTTP Header seetings for HTTP Transport-In). The background is that I can potentially receive very large messages (up to 1.000.000 records - one record having 300 bytes). The data will most likely be split in smaller data chunks of about 50.000 records.

The questions is not about Axis2 Web Service implementation details.

Please also don't propose architecture changes, because that's not possible. We have already tried. ;)

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt an Axis2 processing chain and add a handler which is responsible for the compression/decompression of data. The handlers allow to implement custom processing of messages and imho this is an example of such customization.